# Call url without parameter with webclient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient

I am working on my project.I need to pass URL without parameter with Webclient.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var uri = new Uri("http://misteducation.org/getques.php/testlist", UriKind.Absolute);
webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
webClient.UploadProgressChanged += webClient_UploadProgressChanged;
webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri,"POST",string.Empty);
```

I am using this code, but I am getting an exception.

Comment: What exception? In what line?

Comment: I addded string.Empty because. No parameter needed.

Comment: here i am getting error : void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string jsonstring = e.Result;
       
        }

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Result = 'e.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'

Comment: Well, it seems that that page doesn't exist, it returns 404.

Comment: you can check url....it is working fine. I need to write code to pass url on server that return json data .

Comment: It works in the browser because it is a GET request. You are doing it with POST and the server cannot handle it. I mean, 404 is what the exception says, not what my opinion is.

Comment: Ohhh sorry.....Then suggest me....How i write code  for this particular requirement.

Comment: I don't know what your requirement is nor what is the server logic from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to upload content to a server that most likely does not accept unauthorized uploads (as you are doing by sending a POST request). You need to use [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you may be trying to download string rather than upload.
In that case, you can use either [DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its appropriate handler OR [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which I would personally recommend .